# Does anyone recognize this symbol?

Tags: symbolism, symbols, kumbh-mela, identification-request

My cousin has seen a symbol similar to this at 'Ujjain Simhast Kumbh 2016'. He send this to me wondering if I recognize it, but I don't.

Does anyone know anything about this symbol?

[image]

Comment: Resembles an Urdhva Pundra tilak: http://www.harekrsna.de/tilak/tilakas_s.jpg

Comment: yes it resembles, but there are a lot differences